# How to state each individual solution of an expression is evenly divided by n as opposed to their sum being divided by n

Tags: notation

Given that for k2n (n=4 and k takes all integer values from 1 to n)

If we want to state the **sum of all solutions** is evenly divisible by n we write:

n

∑  k2n = 0   (mod n)

k=0

Is there an equally succinct way to state (in one sentence), that **each solution taken individually**, is evenly divisible by n?

Comment: Solutions of what? I see one "=" and it asserts that n=4. If n=4, isn't 2n=8? Does k2n refer to a sequence of numbers?

Comment: A summation equation involving k(squared)n is given in the 3rd 4th and 5th lines. It is an example of how we state the *sum of all solutions* when integral values of k from 1 to n are substituted into the equation.   What I need to know is a way to state that *each solution taken individually* is evenly divided by n.

Comment: In other words:               Is there an equally succinct way to state (in one sentence), that each solution taken individually, is evenly divisible by n?

12n= 0   (mod n)    Ex. (4*1) = 4 = 0   (mod n)    

22n = 0   (mod n)    Ex. (4*4) = 16 = 0   (mod n)

32n = 0   (mod n)    Ex. (4*9) = 36 = 0   (mod n)

42n = 0   (mod n)    Ex. (4*16) = 64 = 0   (mod n)

Comment: Please see [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on MathJax and any $\LaTeX$ tutorial on the web you like.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean all the squares are divisible by $n$, you can just say $\forall (k)k^2 \equiv 0 \pmod n$.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: The 2 is clearly supposed to be exponent.

Comment: YES Ross you nailed it.  Thank You

Comment: That answers the gist of my question about NOTATION

Comment: PS The tutorial will be helpful in the future - If I have any further questions. But that is it for now.